# How to set a Term into the TaxKeyword field of a file with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I've been working with the **TermStore** in *Microsoft Graph*, using the official documentation I've managed to get a **CRUD system of Terms**. The whole point of the TermStore is *using these terms with files*, so I thought it would be also easy to add those terms into files, foolish of me to think that. I've tried to search, and I didn't find any way to do that, I know using the *SharePoint REST API* or *CSOM* or *PnP* is possible, but it feels to me very anti-intuitive, why Microsoft would give the possibility to perform **CRUD operations on terms**, but then **there is no way to add those terms into files**? Maybe it's just me that I didn't find how to do it.

This is what I've tried:

If I make this HTTP call, the object that I receive **doesn't show** the **Taxonomy property**, so I can't make a *PATCH* call to modify that value because it simply doesn't appear.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}?expand=listItem](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/items/%7Bitem-id%7D?expand=listItem)

And if I do this HTTP call, **the object has the Taxonomy property**

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/Documents/items/{item-id}?expand=fields](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/Documents/items/%7Bitem-id%7D?expand=fields)

So I've tried to make a *PATCH*, sending this to the body

```
{
    "fields": {
        "TaxKeyword@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.Json)",
        "TaxKeyword": [
            {
                "Label": "Test1",
                "TermGuid": "1b20b62d-7ee9-4f55-9ecf-88e622a3f7d7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(I am using **an existing Term** that I've created with the CRUD system, but I don't know how to get the *WssId*, I am not sure if it is necessary or if it is even possible to obtain it)

But it appears the generic error **"invalidRequest"**.

And **is not a problem of permissions**, my app has *Files.ReadWrite.All*, *Sites.ReadWrite.All* and *TermStore.ReadWrite.All*

I hope that there is a solution, and it's just me that I can't search well

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me for the column with the taxonomy property that allows only one value:

First, you need to know the name of the hidden column associated with your column `TaxKeyword`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/columns?$select=hidden,id,name,displayName
```

Find a column `TaxKeyword_0` and use its `id` in the `PATCH` request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{item_id}/fields
{
    "hidden_column_id": "-1;#'TermName'|{TermGuid}"
}
```

Also this should be valid request body

```
{
    "hidden_column_id": "TermName|TermGuid"
}
```

Example of the body in my case:

```
{
    "a2e29228210545d49caf74aef41dea60": "-1;#'senior software engineer'|{5e6730d0-86bf-4913-bfa3-f7369e5bade4}"
}
```

or

```
{
  "a2e29228210545d49caf74aef41dea60": "DevOps|c1276249-3b86-49bd-af51-d89cc2deeac2"
}
```

If the column allows multiple values

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{item_id}/fields
{
    "hidden_column_id": "Term1|Term1Guid;Term2|Term2Guid"
}
```

Example of the body in my case:

```
{
    "o739791951f4466caffa4beeee1091f2": "B_Mala|10e9cc83-b5a4-4c8d-8dab-4ada1252dd70;B_Zadni|2cae6c6a-9bb8-4a78-afff-81b88e735fef"
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that I can not update this field... I really don't understand the point of giving the ability of performing CRUD operations on the TermStore but then you can not do nothing with those terms, it's pointless...

Comment: @Martigeosys Found solution for taxonomy column that allows only one value to be set.   Will try for taxonomy column with multiple values

Comment: Wow, Thank you! But it doesn't appear to me the hidden column, it appears the next ones: TaxKeyword, TaxKeywordTaxHTField and TaxCatchAll, both of these last two are hidden. But even so if I use their name (because the id appears to me that is not recognized) it says to me that it's an Invalid Request. I've tried both options that you mentioned but nothing.

Comment: @Martigeosys Maybe I don't have exactly the same settings for the TaxKeyword column. Could you please share how did you create the taxonomy column?

Comment: Long story short, I was working with Enterprise Keywords, because I thought it was the same. Now I've created a column for the TaxKeywords and works fine! Thank you so much for your help